# Connection reset by peer unless immediately after target machine reboots

Tags: vpn, routing

I have a strange networking problem.  I have a VPN setup on udp:1195 on an office (changed the port from 1194).

The VPN server is 10.9.0.1, my client receives 10.9.0.2 when connected.

I can ping LAN servers (10.217.50.0/24) from my home when VPN connected.

I can ping my VPN client from the lan servers (10.9.0.2).

I can always ssh from LAN server to VPN client. (on 10.217.50.169 >> ssh 10.9.0.2)

I can always ssh from vpn client to VPN server at either its LAN or VPN
address. (on 10.9.0.2 >> ssh 10.9.0.1 or ssh 10.217.50.9)

I can always ssh from vpn client to fios router at the gateway address. (on 10.9.0.2 >> ssh 10.217.50.1)

I can ONLY ssh from vpn client to lan server if the target server just rebooted.  (on 10.9.0.2 >> ssh 10.217.50.169)

If I wait more than a few seconds after the machine has rebooted, I get the following error:

```
ssh user1@10.217.50.169
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 10.217.50.169 port 22
```

The router @ work is a Verizon Fios G1100.  I have a route on it to allow 10.217.50.0/24 to see 10.9.0.0/24.

Any Ideas?

I'm guessing I'm getting blocked by some firewall rule in the router a few seconds after the machine comes online.

It seems that this router doesn't have an option for packet filtering on the firewall web configuration.  I do have ssh access to the firewall and I've confirmed from my vpn, I can ssh to the VPN gateway 10.9.0.1 and the router 10.217.50.1 from my VPN client connection.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very classic routing/backrouting/security problem.

ICMP (ping) messages are used for diagnostic or control purposes. It's errors are directed to the **source** IP address of the originating packet, so ICMP packets are just flowing in both directions.

SSH and other TCP applications use the TCP (three-way-) handshake. And here is the problem: Your VPN client sends data to the 'server' (directly through the NIC of yout VPN server). The server gets it and sends it's answer, technically correct, according to it's routing table to the network's gateway. But the (security) gateway never saw the connection beeing initiated, so the 'unknown'answer is blocked as 'not initiated' oder 'illegal attempt'. This is completely normal, a firewall *should* block half-answered connections.

### How to fix this?

You *could* add a local route to all your servers, pointing to the VPN gateway when trying to reach your VPN LAN. This would be, technically (as network admin) speaking, the "right" solution (as no other components are involved), but a paint in the *** to manage.

You could also check your VPN server and security appliance for the support of ICMP redirection (basically a dynamic route announcement). Which is more or less unlinkely to work flawless.

You could and maybe should stop circumventing your security applicance through this "own" vpn and use the VPN solution provided by it.